# How can I set margin-top to an element without affecting on the row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 14px 3px 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.97);
  border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <span>whatever</span>
</div>
```

I want to bring that star `1px` down. When I set `margin-top: 1px;` to `.fa-star`, the whole row goes down. How can I bring down only that star?

Comment: try adding `position: relative` AND `bottom: 1px` to `.fa-star`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this additional CSS for the font-awesome star:

```
.fa-star {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

It shifts the star 1px down *relative* to its original position without affecting the other elements (that's what the `position: relative` is good for).

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
span{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 14px 3px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: rgba(251,251,251,0.97);
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    color: #666;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
.fa-star {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
<span>whatever</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

setting all elements inside div to vertical-align top|middle

```css
.div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
.div > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.span1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 14px 3px 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.97);
  border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fa-star{
  margin-top:20px; /*change this for 1px*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="div">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <span class="span1">whatever</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using inline-block, with vertical alignment, you will need to use top and relative positioning to move the star. See code example below

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
span{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 14px 3px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: rgba(251,251,251,0.97);
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    color: #666;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}

.fa {
     position:relative;
     top:1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
<span>whatever</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to move the star down `1px` to center it vertically... you could use flexbox to align it (and everything else in the `div`) instead.

You can also remove `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align` from the `span`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 14px 3px 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.97);
  border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <span>whatever</span>
</div>
```